# How to Split a string using VB Macro

Tags: vba

I need to split this number `309701406` as `30` `970` `140` `6`. How can I do with VB macro script. Any one please look into this and assist.

Comment: use mid$() to read the parts at a given offset + length.

Answer (score 4):

AS mentioned in a comment to your Question, you can use the following:

`SomeString = Mid(StringName, Start, Length)`

Putting that into a `Sub` will look as follows:

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub SplitStringSub()

      Dim OriginalString As String

      Dim String1 As String
      Dim String2 As String
      Dim String3 As String
      Dim String4 As String

      OriginalString = 309701406


      'Mid wants a String input
      'Because of the need to split the Numerical String it is not explicity required to have the "  " around then String input line.
      'Should you want to Split a String of Alphabetical Characters the "  " will definitely be required.
      String1 = Mid(OriginalString, 1, 2)
      String2 = Mid(OriginalString, 3, 3)
      String3 = Mid(OriginalString, 6, 3)
      String4 = Mid(OriginalString, 9, 1)

 End Sub
```

Comment: You can actually use this code with loops too if every number in a column needs to be similarly split...

Comment: You need to use the " " for the input string in the event that there are leading 0's that will be stripped off if you treat it as a number,

Comment: Thanks all..It help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

If the 0 is delimiter you can do this.

```
Dim str As String
Dim aTmp() As String

str = "309701406"

aTmp() = Split(str, "0")
str = Join(aTmp, "0 ")
aTmp() = Split(str, " ")
```